# System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager is not resolved

Tags: c#

In my usings I have:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

And then in the code I have:

```
string primary_adrs_key =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrimaryAddressK"];
```

But I get the error:

> "The name ConfigurationManager does not exist in the current context"

Why? What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read  [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

Add the reference System.Configuration.dll in your project

Answer (score 3):

You haven't added reference to System.Configuration. Right click on project and click add references.

[image]